# Json / JsonArray to HashTable / List in Android

Tags: java, android, json, hashtable, arrays

I created a method "Json to HashTable" and vice versa. I use HashTable because "Java" there are no associative arrays. My problem now is when there is an array in the json. This means from "Java" an array of HashTable :/ does not work at all but I think the solution is to use "List >" ...

I see this somewhat complicated. Any help? Is that hard or I complicate too?

Json example:

```
{"Config":[{"Name":"method1","Uses":"0","Event":["Start","Play"],"Action":{"Class":"Ads","Options":{"Class":"Webview","Url":"http:\/\/test.com\/action.php","Time":"10"}}},{"Name":"method2","Uses":"12","Event":["Loading"],"MaxTimes":"5","Options":{"Class":"Ads"}}]}
```

View in: http://json.parser.online.fr/

My code:

```
public Hashtable<?, ?> JSonDecode(String data) {
        Hashtable<String, Object> htJS = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        try {
            JSONObject objJS = new JSONObject(data);
            Iterator<String> it = objJS.keys();
            String key = null;
            Object value = null;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                key = it.next();
                value = objJS.get(key);
                if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                    value = JSonObjectToHashtable(value.toString());
                }
                if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                    value = JSonArrayToHashtable(value.toString());

                }
                htJS.put((String) key, value);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // No valid json
            return null;
        }
        return htJS;
    }

public Hashtable<?, ?> JSonObjectToHashtable(String data) {
        Hashtable<String, Object> htJS = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        JSONObject objJS;
        try {
            objJS = new JSONObject(data);
            Iterator<String> it = objJS.keys();
            String key = null;
            Object value = null;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                key = it.next();
                value = objJS.get(key);
                if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                    value = JSonObjectToHashtable(value.toString());
                }
                htJS.put((String) key, value);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return htJS;
    }

public List<Map<String, Object>> JSonArrayToHashtable(String data) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> listMap = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
        Map<String,Object> entry = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        JSONArray objJSA;

        try {
            objJSA = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < objJSA.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject objJS = objJSA.getJSONObject(i);
                Iterator<String> it = objJS.keys();
                String key = null;
                Object value = null;
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    key = it.next();
                    value = objJS.get(key);
                    if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                        value = JSonObjectToHashtable(value.toString());
                    }
                    entry.put((String) key, value);
                }
                listMap.add(entry);
                entry = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return listMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Map (Hashtable) API is similar to JSONObject API.  There is really no need to convert JSONObject to Map unless your application uses Maps consistently.

If you need to convert JSONObject to Map, the Map can be of type `Map<String, Object>`, where Object can be one of the following types:

- String
- Primitive (Integer, Float, etc)
- Map
- Collection (Array, List, etc) of the tree types mentioned above

Comment: Thanks for responding. Then the best practice to work on Android with Json containing all formats, is working directly with JsonObject and JSONArray?

Comment: It is hard to give an advice because it all depends on the application.  My personal preference is to work with content providers using Cursors, communicate with the servers through Sync Adapters, cache responses (JSON->SQLite) and revalidate UI using ContentResolver.notifyChange(...), but it involves a lot of moving parts.